# Netflix Ribbon with Spring Adding Multiple Clients

Tags: spring, netflix, netflix-feign, netflix-ribbon

My application connects with multiple REST APIs.

I've been successful in adding a Ribbon Client/Load Balance to my application for one of those APIs with its own list of servers

Now I'd like to add a second client that would hold the server list for my second API.

In order to define my client name which is used by Archaius to load specific properties, I added the following property.

```
ribbon.client.name=myFirstClientName
```

My question is: How do I define another client on the same application?

I thought it would be a comma-separated list like:

```
ribbon.client.name=myFirstClientName,mySecondClientName
```

However, this didn't work.

Eventually, I want to end up with two lists of servers like

```
myFirstClientName.ribbon.listOfServers=<ip>,<ip>
mySecondClientName.ribbon.listOfServers=<ip>,<ip>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to make it work by adding a `@RibbonClient` annotation on the interfaces I created for Feign.

The resulting class would be

```
@FeignClient("http://myFirstClientName/")
@RibbonClient(value = "myFirstClientName", configuration = MyFirstClientConfig.class)
public interface MyFirstFeignService {
```

Second Client would be:

```
@FeignClient("http://mySecondClientName/")
@RibbonClient(value = "mySecondClientName", configuration = MySecondClientConfig.class)
public interface MySecondFeignService {
```

Then of course I would set my two lists of server ips

```
myFirstClientName.ribbon.listOfServers=<ip>,<ip>
mySecondClientName.ribbon.listOfServers=<ip>,<ip>
```

PS: Make sure your config classes - MySecondClientConfig and MyFirstClientConfig - above are NOT on the ApplicationContext. Don't let it be caught by some @ComponentScan somewhere or else it won't work.